# I have replaced my starter and battery car won’t start

Tags: starting

I have a 2015 Hyundai Elantra gt. I replaced the starter last fall and the battery a week ago. My car wouldn’t start today after attempting to jump it. Anyone have any suggestions as to why it’s just randomly not starting? Everything was working fine yesterday.

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start the engine?  Do the dash lights light up?  Does the starter motor turn?

Comment: if you want an accurate answer, you will need to supply more information.  Answer what handyhowie asked, as well as explaining "randomly".  We need more info.  Does it shut off after running?  Does it crank at full speed?  etc etc